# Finding image of a real function $f(x) = \frac{\log_a x^4}{\sqrt{1-5x^2}},$.

Tags: calculus, functions

How to find the image of

> $$f(x) = \frac{\log_a x^4}{\sqrt{1-5x^2}}, \qquad a>1.$$

I have tried to find the inverse function - which I didn't succeed. Alternatively, we know that $x^4 > 5 $, and $1-5x^2 \neq 0$. How to proceed?

Thank you.

Comment: see here https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+log2(x%5E4)%2Fsqrt(1-5x%5E2)

Comment: The function is even, and isn't defined in $0$.

Comment: Also as $x\to\pm\frac15$, $f\to\infty$, these are vertical asymptotes.

Comment: Thank you. I have plotted it too. Is there any analytical way to find the image? Or only by complete function investigation?

Comment: For extremes with derivative  $1-5x^2+5x\ln x=0$ can't be solve manual and this need approximation.

Answer (score 0):

it must be $$1-5x^2>0$$ this is equivalent to $$-\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}<x<\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$$ and $$x^4\neq 0$$